# Brahma Sutras or Upanishad quotation needed

Tags: mahabharata, upanishads, brahma-sutras

Where in Brahma Sutras does it say

1. Prutak Upadeshat
2. Tad Gunasaratvad Tu Tad Vyapadesha Prajnavat
3. Jeevo Binnaha Tatha Devaha Tathapi Jnanaroopataha Prochyate Bramha Rupena Na Tu Sarvaswaroopataha

I don't know whether third one is from Upansihads or Mahabharata